# How to edit a checkedListBox within main form from another class?

Tags: c#, winforms

It's probably a silly question, but I really don't know how to handle it.
My main form default class looks like this:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm(bool version)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if(version == true)
        {
            items_checkedListBox.Items.Add("aa".ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            Controls.Remove(items_checkedListBox);
        }
    }
}
```

By default, my `WinForm` app starts with `Application.Run(new MainForm(true));` and everything is ok. But I want to update the checkedListBox from another class and for that I need to instantiate my main form object and I call the new object with `MainForm mainForm = new MainForm(false);` but the problem is that the checkedList control remains, even though `Controls.Remove(items_checkedListBox);` gets executed.

How could I manipulate a control from another class when I instantiate the main form? :(

Comment: First thing that I've noticed, you can use `else`. Second, why you call `InitializeComponent()` in both cases? There is no need to do that, just call it outside `if/else`. Third - why you create  `items_checkedListBox` in first place if you don't need it and want to remove after?

Comment: Thank you for your input, SeM. You are right with your first 2 observations. I will edit my code. I initially open my app with some default settings (checkedListBox available) and after the user sets a radio button I want to repopulate the checkedListBox. The remove method is just an example, the idea is that I want it in the beginning and after the user decides, I want the control altered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing this:

```
MainForm mainForm = new MainForm(false);
```

you create a new second form of the type `MainForm` and delete it's control `items_checkedListBox`, but that's not the control which you see on your first form of `MainForm`. Furthermore you don't see the second form you created, because you didn't make it show up, so don't wonder that you don't see anything happening like the removal of the other control on the second form.

So in order to manipulate your control `items_checkedListBox` you need to pass the reference of this control to your class in which you wish to manipulate it.

Imagine you would have another form (which is your *other class*), which you use to manipulate your control  `items_checkedListBox`.

```
public partial class FmManipulateControl : Form
{
    public FmManipulateControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

In order to be able to do this, pass a reference of this control as method parameter to the constructor:

```
public FmManipulateControl(Control myControl) { ... }
```

So that we can manipulate it we store this reference of our control in a field, so e.g. a button click event can access the control to change/remove/... it.

```
Control controlToChange;

public FmManipulateControl(Control myControl)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    controlToChange = myControl;
}
```

Let's imagine we bind to a button click event in our form `FmManipulateControl`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //diposes the control, so it does not exist anymore, but you can apply
    //any change to the control you wish to do 
    controlToChange.Dispose();
}
```

Now all you have to do is to create an instance of `FmManipulateControl` and pass it a reference of the control `items_checkedListBox` and show the new form object.

```
FmManipulateControl fmChangeAControl = new FmManipulateControl( items_checkedListBox);
fmChangeAControl.Show();
```

---

**Further explaination about the reference type:**

I am talking about *passing a reference of the control* and I think you might wonder about what I mean by that. I suggest you to read about value and reference types.

I try to keep it short and simple.

Imagine a value type contains the value directly itself: e.g. an `int`. The object contains the value directly.

```
int a = 3;
```

`a` contains the value `3`.

Now let's have a look at our control. This ListBox control `items_checkedListBox` does not contain our object control, but a reference to it's location in memory. That's why it is called *reference* type.

So when we pass `items_checkedListBox` as a method parameter, we don't pass an object, but the memory location of our `items_checkedListBox` control. So we point to the same object, so we are abel to manipulate it.

*Note:*

Method parameters are just a copy of the inputted object, so when we do:

```
FmManipulateControl fmChangeAControl = new FmManipulateControl( items_checkedListBox);
```

In our form `fmChangeAControl` we got an object(`myControl`) which is a copy of `items_checkedListBox`. But since we did not pass the object, but a reference it does not matter if we have a copy or not, we still point to the same memory location so we still manipulate the same object.

Comment: I will analyze your explanations and try your code soon. I'll return with an update. Thank you!

Comment: Wow what a detailed answer. Thank you for all the explainations, finally I understand value/reference types atleast a bit.

Comment: I am glad I could help you out as well. :-)

Comment: It works, indeed, Guthardt, thank you!
But when I call the Show method another form pops up (but yes, this one is in the exact shape that I configured). I think I should do a separate constructor for that specific checkedListBox(?) I mean, I am able now to pass as reference my control, but I access it still from my mainForm. Hmm

Comment: @Marko You are talking in miracles, please keep it simple and understandable. What do you want to do? What is your issue?

Comment: I have: public CheckedListBox myControl = new CheckedListBox(); inside my main form class I set into myControl the exact control that I need to alter later. In my radioButton event I create that kind of mainForm once more and I access myControl and alter the desired element. To make the altered object  visible, I have to call the Show() method, but since the object is a mainForm object, when I call Show() another winForm pops up (but yes, it has the right checkListBox content). I am a little confused here. I will read once again more carefully what you have written. Thank you!